# What does "MECHA DEVICE SERVICE" mean in a Sony repair listing?

Tags: sensor, repair, sony

My Sony A7 just came back from the repair with a listing that this part was changed out: [A1976128A](https://www.partstore.com/Part/Sony/Sony/ILCE7/Sony/Sony/A1976128A/New.aspx) — described as "MECHA DEVICE SERVICE". Any idea what it is? I'm guessing it's the sensor, but it's weirdly named... nothing else comes up on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that it's "mechanical device service", and probably just an internal code for tracking the cost of the labor to do the service.

Comment: ah, thanks. it seems to be an eat shoots leaves quandary we figured it to be mechanical device service too, but thought it meant a "device service"  that was mechanical, as opposed to a service on a "mechanical device". thanks much!